# click on button using text appears on the button

Tags: mobile, ui-automation, appium-ios

i am trying to click on a button ('Next'/ 'OK' / 'Cancel') using text appear on the button for iOS app in Appium (as these buttons are common through out the application) , is there any way to use the label of the button and by using class chain strategy or iOS Predicate String Strategy click on it. (**NOTE:** without using Xpath )

I am looking for something like , where i will only pass button name.

```
def clickOnButton("Next"):
```

i have tried
driver.findElementByIosNsPredicate(XCUIElementTypeWindow[label]).click()

Comment: https://github.com/facebookarchive/WebDriverAgent/wiki/Class-Chain-Queries-Construction-Rules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to click `UIAButton` element with `Next` label text you can try to build iOSPredicate this way:

```
driver.findElementByIosNsPredicate("type == 'UIAButton' AND label CONTAINS 'Next'").click();
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you want to link all the elements in one locator and perform an action if any of the label appears.

The code is in java and page factory:

```
    @iOSXCUITFindBy(iOSClassChain = "**/XCUIElementTypeStaticText[`label == \"Next\" OR label == \"OK\" OR label == \"Cancel\"`]")
    public WebElement commonBtn;
```

Even if you don't want to link the elements together use:

```
@iOSXCUITFindBy(iOSClassChain = "**/XCUIElementTypeStaticText[`label == \"Next\"`]")
 public WebElement nextBtn;
```